# Blender 2.82 Mantaflow will not fill volume

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

Using Mantaflow with the new Blender 2.82 release.

Trying to fill a 3 meter long tank with water, but the fluid sim only sloshes on the bottom of the tank without filling up, even after 800 frames @ 30fps… Inflow shoots from outside of the tank but within the Domain cube. Tried setting Liquid radius from 1.00 to 2.00, but still no fill. Tried resolutions at 64, 96, and 128 – no difference.

Tank is extra thick in order not to have FLIP voxel leak into the domain.

Do I need to up the Particle Sampling or the Narrow Band Width to get the tank to fill up?

TIA.

Answer (score 2):

Was able to make it work by tessellating the tank effector to a high mesh.  Large, open, poly faces don't have enough vertices to calculate the containment.